# Debugging storage extension

Tags: 2013-sp1, storage-extensions

I’m having a bit of a nightmare trying to write a storage extension (for Tridion 2013).  So far I have set up the following:

- Running the deployer upload servlet in Tomcat via Eclipse.
- Start the process, drop in a deployer zip package, and successfully deploy.

So all is good with the default set up.  Now I’ve tried to extend the FSPageDAO class.  I’ve updated the cd_storage_conf.xml, and the referenced DAO bundle XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<StorageDAOBundles>
   <StorageDAOBundle type="filesystem">
          <StorageDAO typeMapping="Page"
                 class="com.tridion.storage.extensions.CustomFSPageDAO" />
   </StorageDAOBundle>
</StorageDAOBundles>
```

The class itself does very little at the moment:

```
package com.tridion.storage.extensions;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import com.tridion.broker.StorageException;
import com.tridion.data.CharacterData;
import com.tridion.storage.filesystem.FSEntityManager;
import com.tridion.storage.filesystem.FSPageDAO;

@Component("CustomFSPageDAO")
@Scope("prototype")
public class CustomFSPageDAO extends FSPageDAO
{
    private Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomFSPageDAO.class);

    public CustomFSPageDAO(String storageId, String storageName, File storageLocation, FSEntityManager entityManager)
    {
        super(storageId, storageName, storageLocation, entityManager);
        this.storageId = storageId;
        log.debug("CustomFSPageDAO init. (EM)");
    }

    public CustomFSPageDAO(String storageId, String storageName, File storageLocation)
    {
        super(storageId, storageName, storageLocation);
        this.storageId = storageId;
        log.debug("CustomFSPageDAO init.");
    }

    @Override
    public void create(CharacterData page, String relativePath) throws StorageException
    {
        log.debug("Create.");
        super.create(page, relativePath);
    }

    @Override
    public void update(CharacterData page, String originalRelativePath, String newRelativePath) throws StorageException
    {
        log.debug("Update.");
        super.update(page, originalRelativePath, newRelativePath);
    }

    @Override
    public void remove(int publicationId, int pageId, String relativePath) throws StorageException
    {
        log.debug("Remove.");
        super.remove(publicationId, relativePath);
    }
}
```

When debugging in Eclipse the http upload servlet fails to start, the following is logged:

```
2016-04-17 21:45:41,264 INFO  BundleConfigurationLoader - Custom storage bindings defined, loading customDAOBundle.xml
2016-04-17 21:45:41,275 WARN  BundleConfigurationLoader - CAUTION: Replaced 'Page' for storage 'filesystem' with 'com.tridion.storage.extensions.CustomFSPageDAO'.
2016-04-17 21:45:41,278 INFO  ConfigurationStepLoader - Executing configuration step: FactoryLoader
2016-04-17 21:45:41,323 ERROR StorageManagerFactory - Fatal error, unable to load the StorageManagerFactory
java.lang.ClassCastException: The target class does not match the specified target type
    at com.tridion.util.ReflectionUtil.loadClassInstanceWithTypes(ReflectionUtil.java:83) ~[cd_core.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.util.ReflectionUtil.loadClassInstance(ReflectionUtil.java:108) ~[cd_core.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.storage.filesystem.FSDAOFactory.configureBundle(FSDAOFactory.java:74) ~[cd_datalayer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.storage.configuration.StorageFactoryConfigurationLoader.configureStorage(StorageFactoryConfigurationLoader.java:91) ~[cd_datalayer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.storage.configuration.StorageFactoryConfigurationLoader.configureStorage(StorageFactoryConfigurationLoader.java:65) ~[cd_datalayer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.storage.configuration.StorageFactoryConfigurationLoader.configure(StorageFactoryConfigurationLoader.java:51) ~[cd_datalayer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.configuration.step.ConfigurationStepLoader.configure(ConfigurationStepLoader.java:47) ~[cd_core.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.storage.StorageManagerFactory.configure(StorageManagerFactory.java:137) [cd_datalayer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.services.BaseService.<init>(BaseService.java:113) ~[cd_core.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.storage.StorageManagerFactory.<init>(StorageManagerFactory.java:104) [cd_datalayer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.storage.StorageManagerFactory.reloadInstance(StorageManagerFactory.java:84) [cd_datalayer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.storage.StorageManagerFactory.<clinit>(StorageManagerFactory.java:56) [cd_datalayer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.transport.HTTPSReceiverServlet.init(HTTPSReceiverServlet.java:86) [cd_upload.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1238) [catalina.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1151) [catalina.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:828) [catalina.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:135) [catalina.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106) [catalina.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502) [catalina.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141) [catalina.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [catalina.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616) [catalina.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88) [catalina.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:522) [catalina.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1095) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1502) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1458) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.33]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_60]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_60]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-util.jar:8.0.33]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_60]
```

What is odd, is that I can export this same code from Eclipse, and drop the jar into a http upload site hosted under IIS. Using the same configuration, the class is picked up without issue, and everything logs out as expected.

This would be fine, but it's not a particularly efficient development workflow. Unfortunately Java isn't my strong spot, but I assume it's more an issue with the tooling, as the same code functions under IIS.

Any ideas?

Comment: Could it be that your Eclipse project has some build paths pulling from the wrong locations? E.g. The deployer starts up using a copy of cd_storage_conf.xml from another location?

Comment: Hi Nickoli. Thanks for your reply, but no. I can amend my project DAO bundle XML to use the default class, for example:

`com.tridion.storage.filesystem.FSPageDAO`.

If so, everything works again. So I'm fairly certain the correct configuration is being picked up.

Comment: It might be because you're running on tomcat 8, with probably the JDK 8 under it. Try to run it locally under Tomcat 7 and the JDK 7.

Comment: I've uninstalled Tomcat 8, and installed Tomcat 7. Same issue, all is good when I comment out the storage bindings bundle. When reintroduced, the servlet fails. All is good running the same code/configuration under IIS.

Comment: Your DAO code is missing @Component("CustomFSPageDAO")
@Scope("prototype"). When you are running the code using eclipse (right click - Run as), are you seeing the "cd_datalayer.jar" in the source tab?

Comment: Whilst my example above didn't (edited for completeness), my actual code does include @Component/@Scope.  In the source tab cd_datalayer-7.0.0.jar is listed.

Comment: Hello Andy, were you able to fix this issue, if so how.

Comment: Simple answer, I wasn't.  I just automated the deployment of a compiled jar as much as I could to improve the workflow. Sorry I can't offer more than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been some time but I'll supply an answer provided to me by a chap named Rob van Oostenrijk. It avoids using the Upload and Responder servlet completely.

1. I switched to using a file system publication target, obviously setting the location to the incoming folder configured in the cd_deployer_conf.xml file.
2. In Eclipse, create a new run configuration. In the main tab set the Main class to `com.tridion.deployer.Deployer`.
3. In the Clathpath tab, highlight User Entries. Use the **Advanced** button to add the config folder which contains all the Deployer configurations files. Use the **Add External Jars** button to include all the jars in the Deployer lib found. I removed the previous compiled storage extension code that had been  published there. It should look something like this:[image: Run configuration]
4. Press the **Run** button.

You should now be able to add breakpoints, and see them hit whilst publishing.

Hope this helps, and thanks Rob.